# how to interpet "/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/" line in k3os

Tags: kubernetes, libcrypto

I am running openwrt via plan deployment yaml in k3s which has k3os base image.
The container is not coming up because of the error "/sbin/init: can’t load library ‘libcrypt.so.0’
I have looked for the libcrypt.so.0 library and found the following entries but I am not able to figure out that the library is  used by the container or not.
Here is the oputput of find
"""
sudo find / -name "libcrypt.so.0*"
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/4295/fs/lib/libcrypt.so.0
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/6325/fs/lib/libcrypt.so.0
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/6325/fs/libcrypt.so.0
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/6301/fs/lib/libcrypt.so.0
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/6301/fs/libcrypt.so.0
find: ‘/proc/32072’: No such file or directory

"""

could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the image. I had similar problem and then I found out that image was broken because my local registry could not download the image from docker.io